# Multi-Finger Gestures in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch

I'm running 14.04 on a Lenovo Y500. I want to get multi-touch gestures running, specifically a three-finger swipe to switch desktops. I would like to keep using the Unity interface, so I can't use touchegg, and I have a buttonless touchpad, so easystroke is not a good candidate either.
Is there another third party program that will allow me to use buttonless three finger gestures, or some config hack that will accomplish the same thing?